# Do not ignore excel hidden field VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am trying to use one of the excel hidden field for the purpose of referencing. Basically column(A:A) is hidden and it contains specific IDs that I can use it to reference it to another sheet.

I *could* have moved the column (A:A) further away so that the user does not see it, but my issue is that I have written **too many lines of code already**. I *guess* it is poorly constructed, because if I were to move any of my columns, my entire program would definitely **break**. I *could* try to fix it, but that would mean I would have to over analyze my own code and I either wouldn't understand it or wouldn't find my mistake.

*So,* anyways, I have a Range.Find function, which is looking in the hidden field, but returns nothing. I *could* try to unhide it, and hide it again, but I want to know that if there is a solution in Excel, then to not ignore the hidden field.

Comment: Maybe Application.Match("blah", Columns(1), 0) to get the row number. There are lots of things that work on hidden rows/columns. However, I recommend you fix the *'code that is constructed poorly'*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set myCell = Columns(1).Find("search_string", lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas) 
Debug.Print myCell.Row
```

Replace `"search_string"` to the `ID` you are looking for.